# running a .NET Framework 3.5-based application in .NET Framework 4 getting HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.0, .net-3.5, .net-framework-version

I have assigned a task to debug some issue for a previously build project. When I am running the project in Visual Studio 13 I got below --

[image]

Emphasis on this line--

> this error is because you are running a .NET Framework 3.5-based
>   application in .NET Framework 4

I go through this articles--

[.net 3.5 application on .net 4.0 runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4359266/net-3-5-application-on-net-4-0-runtime)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/version-compatibility

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/how-to-configure-an-app-to-support-net-framework-4-or-4-5

[Problem with .Net Framework 3.5 applications running in .Net Framework 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6227206/problem-with-net-framework-3-5-applications-running-in-net-framework-4)

I placed below code in my webconfig configuration section --

```
<startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" /> 
    <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727" /> 
</startup>
```

But nothing changed. According to this article --

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/install/dotnet-35-windows-10

I enabled .net framework 3.5 in control panel. Still no hope with the same error. Can anyone suggest me how can I get rid of this error or start the project without any problem?

My Web Config is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->

<configuration>

  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
  </configSections>

  <connectionStrings>
  <!--conectionstring is here-->
  </connectionStrings>
  <startup>  
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
    <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>
   </startup>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0"/>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false"/>
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true"/>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
  </appSettings>
  <!--
    For a description of web.config changes for .NET 4.5 see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235367.

    The following attributes can be set on the <httpRuntime> tag.
      <system.Web>
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
      </system.Web>
  -->
  <system.web>
    <!--<httpRuntime executionTimeout="5000"/>-->
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="12288"/>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
        <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <authentication mode="None"/>
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages"/>
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
    <profile defaultProvider="DefaultProfileProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultProfileProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/"/>
      </providers>
    </profile>
    <membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/"/>
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/"/>
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection"/>
      </providers>
    </sessionState>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
  <!-- For ModSecurity-->
   <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
   <ModSecurity enabled="false" configFile="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\owasp_crs\modsecurity.conf"/>
    <!-- For Videos
    <staticContent>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".mp4" mimeType="video/mp4"/>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".m4v" mimeType="video/m4v"/>
    </staticContent>-->
    <!--<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />-->
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit"/>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit"/>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0"/>
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0"/>
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0"/>
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0"/>
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30AD4FE6B2A6AEED" culture="neutral"/>
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0"/>
            </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework"/>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After monitoring the web.config file contents, it was found that following line of configuration was causing the error:

```
<ModSecurity enabled="false" configFile="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\owasp_crs\modsecurity.conf"/>
```

After commenting out that line of code, the error was fixed.

Comment: It is running in the server with no problem.I am tring to running this project in visual studio 13 and getting this error.

Comment: Ok. I believe there is some error in your web.config file. Can your share your web.config after removing sensitive information e.g. database connectionstring etc

Comment: I can not find any web.config in your question

Comment: do you find my web.config in my question now?

Comment: Yes, I noticed the following line:
`<ModSecurity enabled="false" configFile="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\owasp_crs\modsecurity.conf"/>`. Have you tried commenting out this line?

Comment: this works.thanks.can you rewrite your answer pointing this thing then i can accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The error message states that the configuration data is invalid which might have to do with updates to .NET 4.0 as stated on [.NET Framework 4 migration issues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/net-framework-4-migration-issues) section of the [Migration Guide to the .NET Framework 4.7, 4.6, and 4.5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/index):

> Configuration files   The root configuration files (the machine.config
>   file and the root Web.config file) for the .NET Framework and ASP.NET
>   4 have been updated to include most of the boilerplate configuration
>   information that was found in the application Web.config files in
>   ASP.NET 3.5. Because of the complexity of the managed IIS 7 and IIS
>   7.5 configuration systems, running ASP.NET 3.5 applications under ASP.NET 4 and under IIS 7 and IIS 7.5 can result in either ASP.NET
>   errors or IIS errors. Upgrade ASP.NET 3.5 applications to ASP.NET 4 by
>   using the project upgrade tools in Visual Studio 2010. Visual Studio
>   2010 automatically modifies the ASP.NET 3.5 application's Web.config
>   file to contain the appropriate settings for ASP.NET 4.
>
> However, you can run ASP.NET 3.5 applications using the .NET Framework
>   4 without recompilation. In that case, you might have to manually
>   modify the application's Web.config file before you run the
>   application under the .NET Framework 4 and under IIS 7 or IIS 7.5. The
>   specific change you must make depends on the combination of software
>   you are working with, including Service Pack (SP) releases. For
>   information about the possible software combinations that are affected
>   by this change and how to resolve problems with specific combinations,
>   see the section "Configuration Errors Related to New ASP.NET 4 Root
>   Configuration" in the document [ASP.NET 4 Breaking Changes](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=182908) on the
>   ASP.NET Web site.

[ASP.NET 4 Breaking Changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/whitepapers/aspnet4/breaking-changes#configuration-errors-related-to-new-aspnet-4-root-configuration) states two sources of errors:

1. incorrect merger of machine.config and Web.config
2. configuration comparison fails due to version numbers not matching

Another option might be to change the order of the framework specification as it will use them in the preferred order from top to bottom as stated in [Version Compatibility in the .NET Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/version-compatibility#Apps):

So perhaps this will work as well:

```
<startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727" /> 
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" /> 
</startup>
```